# Gsteeamer rtsp video streaming freezes very often for lorex rtsp stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I am using following pipeline command and I am seeing video is freezing every 5mins . Any idea what I am missing ? is there any way freezing can be avoided ? I checked and confirmed that my network bandwidth is not an issue at all for below command.

```
GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0  flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! rtmpsink sync=false location="rtmp://xxxxxxx" rtspsrc location="rtsp://xxxxxx" caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MPA, payload=(int)96" ! rtpmpadepay !  mpegaudioparse ! queue ! mad ! audioconvert ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg,mpegversion=4,stream-format=raw ! mux. rtspsrc location="rtsp://xxxxxx" caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,byte-stream=false ! decodebin ! x264enc threads=4 speed-preset=ultrafast bitrate=3072 ! mux.
```

I also see following output repeated many times in terminal.

0:10:11.187436105 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42367 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187556453 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42368 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187665149 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42369 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187740293 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42370 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187804924 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42371 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187868380 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42372 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping
0:10:11.187953604 20214 0x7f3180005d90 WARN         rtpjitterbuffer gstrtpjitterbuffer.c:2349:gst_rtp_jitter_buffer_chain: Packet #42373 too late as #9598 was already popped, dropping

Can anyone help to resolve this freeze issue in gstreamer-1.0 (ubuntu 14.04) ?

Answer (score 0):

The freezing occurs when frames are not arriving in time, or there is a synchronization problem. Play with the Bitrate and reply how it affects the duration that the stream is working / how long it takes until freezing occurs.

I read up on this using: https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/issues/299 thread, maybe you will find this useful? Keep us updated.